# Expire a particular page on back button of browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

if users press the browser's back button to reach the prior page, the page should display a message like "web page expired".

can i use javascript for this???

for example:
there are 4 pages in web sites. on page 1,2 and 3 the user can use the back-button, wheras on the 4th page the user gets the desired message.

i thought that i can do this by using counter.

i used following javascript on the master page ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GoBack() {
        window.history.go(+1);
    }
</script>
```

and call the function in body like this:

```
<body onload="GoBack();">
```

and on the 4th `page_load` i do the following:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

it is working for all pages .. but i want to do this only for the 4th page

Comment: @eugeneK: I shall prefer a hidden field in the page than a sessionstate. Session gets turbid very early.

Comment: @kangkan: a `HiddenField` will only work if you have posts between your page loads ... i suppose usage of `Session`

Comment: @eugeneK: If you look at the question, it is about a reload. So, I talked about viewstate. If somebody need to put such counter in multiple places, using session state will make the session heavy, while using something like a viewstate will keep the management easy.

Comment: @kangkan: what is a reload?? ... hitting `F5`, causing a post, causing another get (eg. pressing enter in the input-url-line)???!! ... damn: for god's sake, he should elaborate!

Comment: Why don't you edit and update the question?

Comment: @Andreas: Are you getting restless?

Comment: @ankush: nope ... the session with its variables resides on the server. as reading through your other questions, it seems that the `web page expired`-message is intention. have you even tried the `session`-option?!

Comment: sorry for this kind of question .. this is not well formed.

Comment: it's not about the kind of the question, it's about how you have asked and included (or better: not included) details :) ...

Comment: @ankush: accept an answer of any of your questions as solution.

Comment: @ankush: i strongly advise you to give `Session` s a try. if you experience any problems with using sessions (eg. loosing data), you could start another question or (better) first give the search a try. people are more willed to help if they see that the queriest tried something on his/her own

Comment: @ Andreas: i am using session. my all value is coming from session

Comment: @ Andreas: i have updated this question. please have a loook

Comment: @ankush: you need to support more code that anyone can help you! give us some code-behind demo-code, some html-markup (if you have any special in there which may influences sessions) ...

Comment: @ankush: you should not rewrite your question to something, that does not match the original one ... this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316062/if-users-press-the-browsers-back-button-to-reach-the-prior-page-then-page-shou

Comment: @Ankush: Are you anywhere near your answer?

Comment: @Kangkan: hi Kangkan, i have done these things... i used popup menu...

Answer (score 2):

If you only want it on that page level, and when you use postbacks, then I suggest you simply keep it in **ViewState** instead of Session state. Session's also still available on other pages, where you might want to have other counters.

Comment: ? If he simply fills up ViewState with 1 on the first request and on successive postbacks increases it in the Page_Load he can use it.

Comment: which page, that you know, behaves that way to track users?!

Comment: For tracking users I hope none whatsoever. But his originally question, before editing it 2 times, didn't mention anything about tracking users. Just simply a counter on how many times a page got loaded. Since ViewState is a per user & per page state management mechanism in ASP.NET it is, for the original question, a possible way to accomplish that.

Comment: basically: tracking = counter... how can you say that there are posts? it was about reloads. so `viewstate` might not be the correct solution! you should have suggested that the queriest has to elaborate or your answer matches every possiblity (which you not did ...) :)

Comment: I guess I interpreted the original question as being that the page was reloaded by genuine postbacks which is the standard way in ASP.NET.

Comment: :) ... that was, what my downvote was about ... you should state sth like `if you use postbacks, you could do ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the variable alive across requests. So one way is to put it in some viewstate or sessionstate. Sessionstate is least preferred. But you can possibly put it in a hidden textbox in the page and simply use it.

Looking at the problem after the much awaited update/edit, I shall suggest you to use SessionState. Please give a try on it.

Comment: -, `ViewState` will only work if he uses posts ... + for `Session`